# how can i get the name and quantity of products in tpl file

Tags: php, opencart

I m working on the integration of a new payment gateway in an open-cart in which i have almost succeeded. The only problem which i m facing is that i m not able to post the name and quantity of the products.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code and describe in more detail where you are unable to post things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = $this->cart->getProduct();
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product['name'] . ' - ' $product['quantity'] . '<br />';
}
```

will echo

> Name - Quantity
>
> Name - Quantity

so you just need to edit accordingly for your needs

Comment: Thanx alot Jay for the answer.